# Help prove $f(x)= 0$ for all $x$ when the set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is dense

Tags: calculus, continuity, proof-writing

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has the property that $f$ is continuous and $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\in S$, where $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is dense. Prove that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  Do you know **precisely** what "dense" means?

Comment: yes, Dense is for every interval (a,b) in R there is some s in S with s in (a,b). I am just having trouble on where to start

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $\{x\in\mathbb{R}| f(x) = 0\}$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For any real $x$ you can choose a sequence $s_n \to x$ where $s_n \in S,$ since $S$ is assumed dense.

Comment: thats great! but where do i start with the proof

Comment: Start as in hint, then use for continuous $f$ that $f(\lim s_n)=\lim(f(s_n)).$ In your case each $f(s_n)=0.$